# scrapy LOG_FILE and LOG_LEVEL setting does not work per spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have several spiders in my project, and I want to log every spider in independent log file (such as brand.log, product.log ...).

So I use the `custom_settings` per spider, but it doesn't seem to work. Is it a bug until now? Is there any easy config can solve this problem?

Very thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me. Here is the spider inside a dummy project:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_FILE': '/tmp/example.log',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('XXXXX')
```

I start the spider using `scrapy crawl example` and the log file is successfully written to `/tmp/example.log`.

Comment: what version of scrapy are you using, my version is 1.3.3

Comment: @freyr Tested on 1.4.0. How do you run the spider?

Comment: Right @TomášLinhart, this was fixed in [Scrapy 1.4.0](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#bug-fixes): https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1612